# Why is my bootstrap navbar styling lost when going to mobile site

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

At the top of my website I have included a standard, fixed-top bootstrap navbar and have not added any other CSS on top of the bootstrap default. Even with this I find that when shrinking the window to mobile (below 767px) the styling goes crappy. A margin is added at the top and bottom of the buttons and as you go smaller the about button on the right goes completely out of alignment. Does anyone know a fix for this. I have tried just going and tweaking the css to fix the problem but with no success.

Here is the code for the navbar:

```
    <?php 

    $pg = pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);

    if ($pg == "index") {
      $navbarposition = "navbar-fixed-bottom";
    } else {
      $navbarposition = "navbar-fixed-top";
    }

    echo "<body>";
    echo "<nav class='navbar navbar-default " . $navbarposition . " navbar-inverse' role='navigation'>"

    ?>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li id="about" <?php if($pg == 'about'){echo 'class="active"';} ?> ><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
            <li id="staff" <?php if($pg == 'staff'){echo 'class="active"';} ?> ><a href="staff.php">Staff</a></li>
            <li id="contact" <?php if($pg == 'contact'){echo 'class="active"';} ?> ><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            <li id="calendar" <?php if($pg == 'calendar'){echo 'class="active"';} ?> ><a href="calendar.php">Calendar</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </body>
```

Thanks

Kabeer

Comment: You should include the smallest amount of code possible to reproduce the issue you are having as a snippet if possible. It helps people help you and keeps the Question relevant if your link disappears. Also, the only reference you supplied doesn't display the issue and might be considered to only be promoting your site.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code

Comment: @klors The problem is that I do not have any other code than the bootstrap default. I have included the code for the navbar in the question now

Comment: I am annoyed and confused as to why I am being downvoted for no reason. Can someone please explain what I have done wrong?

Comment: Can't you override the CSS for the nav using a media query after the bootstrap.css in your own file?

Comment: This is a styling question and too localized. You will need to go over your CSS in order to find where the margins/padding is coming from. Use some of the style inspectors in current web browsers. PHP has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution to my problem. For anyone else who finds this in the future just download a customised version of bootstrap from this page: http://getbootstrap.com/customize and set @grid-float-breakpoint variable to 1px.